# Enterprise library dbcommand addoutparameter with stored procedure in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, output, enterprise

**My stored procedure:**

CREATE DEFINER=`AS0058`@`%` PROCEDURE `getName`(IN eid INT,INOUT ename VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
Select fname into ename from emp where empid=eid;
END

**ASP.NET C# program using enterprise library:**

DbProviderFactory dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.Odbc");
            string connect = "Dsn=emp;uid=AS0058;pwd=best@123";
            Database db = new GenericDatabase(connect, dbProviderFactory);
          DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("{call `getName`(?,?)}");
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "empid", DbType.Int32, 2);
            db.AddOutParameter(cmd,"fname",DbType.String,45);
            //db.DiscoverParameters(cmd);
            db.ExecuteScalar(cmd);// The error is thrown at this place:OUT or INOUT psuedo variable trigger
            string results = Convert.ToString(db.GetParameterValue(cmd,"fname"));
             MessageBox.Show(results);

Please suggest me a solution: